# How to put cscope output in Vim quickfix window?

Tags: vim, cscope, errorformat

I want to redirect output from cscope to Vim quickfix window. The glue part is easy enough, but I currently stuck at errorformat. Here's an example from cscope output (cscope -L -1 bar):

```
Format: "filename scope linenumber sourceline"
Example: "abc.cpp foo 25 bar()"
```

This means inside foo(), at line 25 in abc.cpp there is a call to bar().

`efm = %f\ %*[^\ ]\ %l\ %m` works but the scope information is lost. For example:

```
Input: "abc.cpp foo 25 bar()" becomes
Output: "abc.cpp |25| bar()"
```

What I want is to include the scope in quickfix window, like this:

```
Input: "abc.cpp foo 25 bar()" becomes
Output: "abc.cpp |25| bar() inside foo()"
```

Is it possible to do this with errorformat only, or do I need to write a script to manipulate the output before feeding it to Vim?

Comment: This maybe helpful so I just put here: One can connect the output of a program to Vim quickfix with `:cex`. For example: `:cex system("cscope -L -1 " . expand("<cword>"))<CR>`. Personally, I use this with cppcheck and vera++ for static analysis of C++ code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of messing about with `errorformat`, just set `cscopequickfix` and use the normal `:cscope` commands. eg. (from vim help)

```
:set cscopequickfix=s-,c-,d-,i-,t-,e-
```

Edit

You could also use a filter like the following to reorder the fields

```
sed -e 's/^\([^ ]\+\) \([^ ]\+\) \([^ ]\+\) \(.*\)$/\1 \3 \4 inside \2/'
```

set it to filter your message, then use the `efm`

```
errorformat=%f\ %l\ %m
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about cscopequickfix before. This seems to work fine btw, so upvote for you. However, this still does not answer my question about matching output with errorformat. It can help to connect output of other programs where there are no built-in.

Comment: @ThanhDK: I've added a small filter script to do what you want, which is what the vim help suggests you do if the messages don't fit the format string

Comment: to use cscopequifix you need to have quickfix module disable. Saving time from other adding it to your answer plz.